# How do I override variables in Android debug VS release vs main?

Tags: java, android

I have a variable that I would like overridden with src/debug/java version when I'm in debug mode:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
```

I tried putting the variable in src/debug/java to be true, and src/main/java to be false, but it does not get overridden.  Is there a way to do this or a workaround?

I tried the following in my build.gradle, but regardless of release or debug mode, it

```
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "false"
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "true"
    }
```

And my java:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "BuildConfig.REPORT_CRASHES: " + BuildConfig.REPORT_CRASHES);
    // Both debug and release versions display 'true'
```

Comment: The way you describe it, it should work. Perhaps post a screenshot of your folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your com.main.module.BuildConfig VS your com.dependency.module.BuildConfig...this will solve all problems.

Answer (score 3):

Per the example on [this blog](http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/), you can use `buildConfigField` in your gradle files to add additional variables to your `BuildConfig` class:

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_FLAG", "false"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "DEBUG_FLAG", "true"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then reference it in code by using `BuildConfig.DEBUG_FLAG`. Note that `BuildConfig` already contains a `DEBUG` flag which is `true` in all except `release` builds.

Comment: Great recommendation.  See my edits above.  I"m not sure why but everything returns true.

Comment: Are you switching between your debug/release builds via the build variants window? One thing to note is that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` already does what you have written in your update.

Comment: I am encountering this error with variants, and this is probably why I can't resolve the issue at large:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434962/how-do-i-change-the-build-variant-for-a-library-dependency-module