# How do I change the build variant for a library dependency module?

Tags: java, android

I have a 'mobile' module that depends on a 'core' module, and I keep getting the same inconsistent error:

mobile/build.gradle:

```
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://mobile.debug\""
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://mobile.release\""
    }
```

core/build.gradle:

```
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://core.debug\""
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEARCH", "\"https://core.release\""
    }
```

Whenever I set my variants to be mobile debug + core debug, I still get the same output inside my core.MyApplication.java file:  'https://core.release':

[image: mobile+core in debug variant]

Answer (score 2):

Whenever your modules imports another dependency-module, the dependency-module uses it's 'release' variant.

See: [BuildConfig.DEBUG always false when building library projects with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176284/buildconfig-debug-always-false-when-building-library-projects-with-gradle)

The solution for this is to use your com.main.module.BuildConfig.DEBUG variables, and not your com.dependency-module.BuildConfig.DEBUG...cause this debug will always be false.